# Can an Insert lock a select/select count(*) or otherwise?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I have multiple worker processes that read and insert data into the same postgresql database. But sometimes, there seems nothing to be happening at all. Could it be that the select or insert of one process may block/lock the insert or select of another process?

Comment: Do you use explicit locking?  And what is the isolation level of the competing transactions?

Comment: I do not use explicit locking. I don't know about the isolation level.

Comment: What does `SHOW default_transaction_isolation` say?

Comment: it says "read committed".

Comment: Then (unless you get deadlock errors) I'd say there is no database level blocking - maybe some sort of I/O problem?  What are your queries which run when this happens?

Comment: Please show some code so we can verify that this is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use `LOCK TABLE .. EXCLUSIVE` there is no way to block a `SELECT` statement in Postgres.

An `INSERT` however *can* be blocked by another transaction trying trying to insert the same primary key value.

If you experience a situation where "nothing seems to happen", you can query [`pg_stat_activity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) and check the `waiting` column to see if any connection is blocked.

Answer (score 2):

The question is short on specifics, but yes it's quite possible for writers to block other writers. In a multiple workers scenario, this is one of the things you need to worry about when designing the code.

Common operations like writing to a row that another session has written to and not yet committed will block in the default isolation mode. Inserting into a table with a unique index will also block until another session doing the same operation has not committed or rolled back.

Having the transactions as short-lived as possible may mitigate the problem. If you need to count(*) on large tables, don't do that, use pre-computed counters instead (see [Slow_Counting](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting)).

To check for locks when the problem happens, see the queries in [Lock_Monitoring](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring).

Comment: Interesting answer. :) But I think this is only relevant for a high-concurrency system. From the question I would assume a simple worker model with only one system, which means there are a maximum of 8 or 16 workers. And in this case I think your points aren't valid.

Comment: If 2 workers can produce the described side effects (if they are correctly designed and implemented), you shouldn't use a multi worker model in the first place :)